# How to create maven module for Spring Roo project?

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse, spring-roo

I have Spring Roo project. It is maven project. So I would like to use maven modules to make my growing project modular.
However when I try to create module project( with m2eclipse right-click project, then Maven -> New Maven Module Project). It is created OK, it get's all maven dependencies/libraries from parent project.

But:
1) I cannot use classes from parent project (even though "Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects" is checked)

2) I cannot use Roo shell.
I can run shell, but cannot add entity. 
And I can't add persistence.

```
roo> persistence setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY
additionalBuildcommands element of the maven-eclipse-plugin required
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But: 1) I cannot use classes from parent project (even though "Resolve
>   dependencies from Workspace projects" is checked)

That's right. parent projects of multi-module projects must have packaging pom, which means that no classes will be compiled. A parent project should be a wrapper for multiple child projects, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As of August 2011 it is impossible.
I only managed to move domain class with roo dependencies into separate maven project.
Then I can add it as dependency.

Create maven modules is expected in Spring Roo >= 1.2.M2